# Sampling an N-dimensional copula via N independent uniforms

Tags: probability, sampling, copula

In order to draw a sample from an N-dimensional Gaussian copula, we draw N independent standard Gaussian random variables, form a vector, and multiply it by an appropriate matrix (Cholesky and such). Each independent standard Gaussian can be computed by drawing a sample from the uniform distribution on [0, 1] followed by an application of the inverse of the standard Gaussian CDF.

**Question**: Given an arbitrary N-dimensional copula and N independent samples uniformly distributed on [0, 1], is it possible to demonstrate that there is always a transformation which allows one to obtain a sample from the copula using only the uniform samples?

**Update**: I’m aware of the [Rosenblatt transformation](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177729394). The inverse of this transformation might be an answer to my question. I don’t have deep knowledge in this area, and I’m looking for a person who could consolidate all ideas and describe the whole process step by step.

Comment: What kind of "transformation" are you looking for?  I am puzzled, because according to the definitions of copula I know (such as in Nelsen's book), it is *defined* as a distribution $F$ on $[0,1]^N$, so one can "sample" from it with a uniform vector $(x_1,\ldots,x_N)$ merely by computing $F(x_1,\ldots,x_N)$.

Comment: @whuber, I’m looking for a transformation that would turn N independent uniformly distributed random variables into N dependent uniformly distributed random variables according to the copula. $F(x_1, \dots, x_N)$ is just a single value, isn’t it? Or may be I’m missing your point. Can you please elaborate a bit? Thank you.

Comment: Are you perhaps asking the multidimensional generalization of the question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124865/sampling-from-conditional-copula?

Comment: @whuber, thank you for your time. It’s certainly related, but not quite. I’m trying to find a way to correlate independent variables according to a given copula. Please have a look at the update in the original post.

Comment: Is there even such a thing as a non-uniform joint distribution with uniform marginals?

Comment: @ssdecontrol *Every* copula but one produces an example of a non-uniform joint distribution with uniform marginals!  Ivan: In what sense do you mean "not quite"? That approach I linked to sounds identical to the process Rosenblatt describes on the first page of his paper and it appears to address your question.

Comment: @whuber, I apologize: now I think you were right with your previous question to me. Partial derivatives confused me a bit. So, the inverse of Rosenblatt’s transformation would be the generalization of what Nelsen is talking about, right?

Comment: Yes, I think so.