# How to generate correlated non-normal random variables?

Tags: correlation, simulation, random-variable, random-generation

I know that the Cholesky decomposition can be used to generate correlated normal random variables. 
Is there similar method to generate correlated random variables with non-normal distributions?

Comment: Look at the specific answers found by searching our site for [copula](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=copula+generation).  [Related searches](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=copula+random) will turn up more general answers, too, such as http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133881/how-can-i-generate-random-numbers-from-any-given-copula.

Answer (score 1):

I like the question and am "thinking out loud" in this response. It's too long for a comment and not specific enough to constitute a real "answer." However, these observations may be useful in helping to outline or bound the problem. Also, I should note that I'm not an expert in this area and may miss important aspects of the problem.

In parsing the query, there are several phrases that require elaboration:

1) *Non-normal distributions* What is meant by these words? The normal distribution is very robust to violations of normality. So, how "non-normal" does an empirical PDF have to be? Is it as simple as identifying a distribution function different from the normal that generates random numbers consistent with the assumptions for that distribution?

2) *Correlation* A naive interpretation would imply either Pearson or Spearman pairwise measures of association (linear in the former, monotonic in the latter). However, *correlation* can also refer to discrete, nonlinear and/or complex dependence structures requiring different measures of association and dependence such as Somer's *D*, distance correlations, Mutual Information Criterions, and so on, as appropriate.

3) *Cholesky decomposition* (CD) This technique is appropriate for linear decompositions. To the extent that the new distributions diverge from "linearity," it is less appropriate as a tool.

The easiest part in all of this is generating the random numbers appropriate for and based on some pre-determined, "non-normal" distribution. The next step would be to identify and utilize a metric appropriate for any resulting association or dependence structures that are a function of that distribution. Then, a framework is required that develops simulated, "correlated* random variates based on this metric. To me, this isn't straightforward since it may include replacing the CD with a new, more appropriate approach.

It's at this point that I run out of ideas since the limits of what I know don't permit me to determine if replacement of the CD is needed or, if so, what a useful replacement might be. It sounds like a good topic for someone's dissertation.

Anyway, apologies for the lack of a specific answer. Hope this is useful. I'll be interested in any reactions, positive or negative.

Comment: See the links I provided in a comment to the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/83158)

Comment: @SeanEaster  The lack of a specific answer was noted in the response.