Bivariate data generation of inverse exponential distribution
With the following bivariate inverse exponential distribution, I must create data from a random vector: $$ F_{X,Y}(x,y) =\exp({-x^{-1}-y^{-1}-\theta {(xy)}^{-1}}),0\leq\theta\leq 1, x,y>0.$$ I know how to create and transform data from a univariate using a uniform random variable (I'm using $\texttt{R}$), but I don't know how to do the same for a random vector. Do you have any recommendations?

Good search terms are simulate copula, because this is readily converted into a copula in a standard form.  You still need to merge your accounts, btw.

I'll merge later definitely. I can convert this CDF into copula. Can I find a method how to generate data after converting into copula because that's what I am not finding

See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/134140/919 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/654402/919.
