# R - generating bi-variate correlated t-student with specific mean and variance

Tags: r, monte-carlo, t-distribution

I have two correlated time series (stock returns a and b).
The two stock return series have empitical correlation rho, averages mu.a/mu.b, and standard deviation sd.1/sd.b.
I am getting the degree-of-freedom fit with QRM package, and have nu.a and nu.b degrees of freedom

**What I am trying to do**: generate two correlated t-student distributions with the same mean and variance than in the sample.
Coding is in R.

What I have done thus far:

1. Generated two independent Gaussians [0,1]
2. Turned them into correlated uniforms (with the empirical correlation rho)
3. Transformed them in t-student distributions by feeding the uniforms to the CDF of t-student

Code:

```
# draw standard normal samples
z1 = rnorm(N) ; z2 = rnorm(N)

# generate correlated uniforms
u1 = pnorm(z1)
u2 = pnorm(rho*z1 + sqrt (1-rho)*z2 )

# feeding to student-t
t1 = qt(u1,nu.a)
t2 = qt(u1,nu.b)
```

My question is, how do I "scale" those to the empirical data that I am trying to simulate? I am using a linear transformation but I'm not sure it's the correct way

```
a.ret = a.mu + sd.a * t1
b.ret = b.mu + sd.b * t1
```

Any help much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: The most standard approach to generating correlated variates with fixed and known marginals is to use [copulas](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/158375/7224). This does mean you can set the covariance without trial-and-error, though.